# Fourier's Method Question

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I've been asked to use Fourier's method to obtain the following solution;

$$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n e^{-(n \pi C / L)^2 t} \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L})$$
$$B_n = \frac{2}{L} \int_0^L \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L}) f(x) dx$$

for the 1-D heat equation for $t>0$, on the region $0 \leqslant x \leqslant L$ with the boundary conditions $u(0,t) = 0 = u(L,t)$, $t > 0$ and initial condition $u(x, 0) = f(x)$, $0 \leqslant x \leqslant L$.

So, to achieve this, I started off with the 1-D heat equation; $u_t = c^2 u_{xx}$, and set $u(x,t) = X(x) T(t)$. Then, with a bit of working, I've found; $$T(t) = Ae^{-c^2 t}$$
$$X(x) = B \sin(c x) + C \sin(c x)$$
Now, using my initial conditions on $x$, I was able to get $X(x) = B \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L})$, with $c = \frac{n \pi}{L}$. Thus, this made $T(t) = Ae^{-(\frac{n \pi}{L})t}$. Putting this all together, I've got...
$$u(x,t) = D e^{-(\frac{n \pi}{L})^2t} \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L})$$ With $D = AB$.

Now, from here, I'm a bit confused as to what results I should be getting. If I use the initial condition $u(x,0) = f(x)$, I get something that resembles the $B_n$ I'm meant to acquire. But, I'm not really sure where to go from here. Any help would be fantastic!! :)

Comment: You have a family $u_n$ of solutions to the heat equation satisfying the boundary conditions. The equation as well as the boundary conditions are linear, so any linear combination of the $u_n$ also satisfies them. Now try to write the initial value as a linear combination of the $u_n(x,0)$. Normally, that doesn't quite work out, since the Fourier series of $f$ has infinitely many nonzero terms, but that doesn't really matter, because in a sensible way, the Fourier series converges, and the heat equation and boundary conditions are compatible with that convergence.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm slightly confused as to what you mean. I understand that it's going to converge, given the boundary conditions, but I'm not sure what you mean by $u_n$??

Comment: $u_n(x,t) = e^{-c_n^2t)}\sin (k_nx)$, with $k_n = n\pi/L$, and $c_n = c\cdot k_n$. These are the building blocks from which you assemble your solution.

Comment: Thank you!! I was able to combine your hints with a bit of research I did. I came across this resource: http://www.aerostudents.com/files/differentialEquations/fourierSeries.pdf

I found it explained my problem fairly well, but I do have one more question - in tutorials, we were told to solve for $X(x)$ and $T(t)$, with constant terms out the front. Why is it that here, they are omitted??

Comment: Do they just get absorbed into the $B_n$ term??

Comment: I have no idea what "solve for $X(x)$ and $T(t)$, with constant terms out the front" means :-/. The principle I know is "find simple solutions of the equation, and try to combine them to fit the initial value". Of course for linear equations. If I make a guess, then I'd say that yes, they're absorbed in the $B_n$ coefficients.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make what I was asking very clear - but I get what I'm doing. Thank you very much!!

If I could trouble you for one more question, we were asked to write out the first few terms in the case that $f(x) = u_0$. Now, I've gone ahead and done that, and found that my $$B_n = \frac{4u_0}{(2n-1)\pi}$$
In my series expansion, do I have to set the $n$ in the exponential to $2n - 1$ also??

Comment: It's probably clear to people who have learned the terminology. I haven't. To answer the question in the comment, no, the $n$ in the exponential is the index in $B_n$, so you get $$\sum_n \frac{4u_0}{(2n-1)\pi}e^{-\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2t}\sin \left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right).$$